# "Invalid cross-device link" hard for directories on the same filesystem

Tags: command-line, partitioning, hard-link

I know hard links can't cross filesystems, but trying to link files via bind mounts that physically live on the same filesystem fails as well. I detailed things below to visualize it better, but the TLDR of my question is why is `ln` treating the mounted directories as though they live separately?

Basically, copying files into a share folder would be best-served with hardlinks so I'm not duplicating space:

```
mymedia/
├─ share/
│  ├─ pics/
│  │  ├─ pic2.tif
│  ├─ vids/
│  │  ├─ vid1.mov
├─ homevid/
│  ├─ vid1.mov
│  ├─ vid2.mov
│  ├─ vid3.mov
├─ homepic/
│  ├─ pic1.tif
│  ├─ pic2.tif
├─ training/
```

`mymedia/share` is on one drive (Media1), whereas `homepic` is on Media2 and `homevid` on Media3. The two folders in `share` are mounted from Media2/Media3. This is from fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_1 /mnt/Media1 auto 0 0  
/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_2 /mnt/Media2 auto 0 0  
/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_3 /mnt/Media3 auto 0 0  
/mnt/Media1 /mnt/mymedia none bind 
/mnt/Media2/homepic /mnt/mymedia/homepic none bind
/mnt/Media2/share /mnt/mymedia/share/pics none bind
/mnt/Media3/homevid /mnt/mymedia/homevid none bind
/mnt/Media3/share /mnt/mymedia/share/vids none bind
```

I can create the link while using the "real" path, like so: `ln /mnt/Media2/homepic/pic2.tif /mnt/Media2/share/`, and see the new file in both directories; `stat` confirms the inode is the same for the files, as well as same device:

| Path | Device |
| --- | --- |
| /mnt/Media2/homepic | 831h/2097d |
| /mnt/Media2/share | 831h/2097d |
| /mnt/mymedia/homepic | 831h/2097d |
| /mnt/mymedia/share/pics | 831h/2097d |
| /mnt/mymedia/training | 821h/2081d |

Unfortunately, using the bind mounts would be way better for my workflow (this fails): `ln /mnt/mymedia/homepic/pic1.tif /mnt/mymedia/share/pics/pic2.tif`

What am I missing?

Comment: You seem to have error in your fstab: you bind-mount both `Media2` and `Media3` to the same directory `/mnt/mymedia/share/pics`. If I understood correctly, these are different devices. Even if not, it doesn't make sense to have them bind-mounted to the same dir. And I guess that leads to the `ln` error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; that was a transcription error on my part and I edited the post. The `vids` and `pics` folders in `mymedia/share` each live on Media3/2.  Maybe I still have an error though that I'm not catching, unless it has something to do with the parent (`mymedia/share`) living on Media1?

Comment: `/dev/sda1 /mnt/Media1 /mnt/mymedia none bind` doesn't look like a valid fstab line. `/dev/sdb1 /mnt/Media2 none bind` is not a bind mount, your are mounting a device here, same for `/dev/sdc1 /mnt/Media3 none bind`. Device names like `/dev/sda1` should be avoided, use UUID or file-system labels to identify correct partitions.

Comment: Can you please confirm if `df /mnt/mymedia/homepic/pic1.tif /mnt/mymedia/share/pics/` *(that is, `df` command over the parameters that make `ln` fail, except the second one is a dir, not a filename which wasn't created)* shows the same device for both arguments?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: it returns that they're on the same device: 
```lang-bash $ df /mnt/mymedia/homepic/pic1.tif /mnt/mymedia/share/pics/ 
Filesystem       1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sdb1      13563485152 9514471848 3365377900  74% /mnt/mymedia/homepic/ 
/dev/sdb1      13563485152 9514471848 3365377900  74% /mnt/mymedia/share/pics/ 
```

I guess I'm not sure whether to be thrilled or not! :)

**EDIT:** My triple-backticks are getting garbled. Sorry!

Comment: @mook765 - You're right, it's not; that was another mistake of mine typing absent coffee. I updated by UUID and remounted. This should look more proper hopefully: 
```lang-bash

/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_1 /mnt/Media1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Media1 0 0 
/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_2 /mnt/Media2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Media2 0 0  
/mnt/Media1 /mnt/mymedia none bind 
/mnt/Media2/share /mnt/mymedia/share/pics none bind 
/mnt/Media2/homepic /mnt/mymedia/homepic none bind``` **EDIT:** My triple-backticks are getting garbled. Sorry!

Comment: The fstab you provide here is still a mess, take a look at the third line: `/mnt/mymedia/share none bind ` is not a valid fstab line. Also now I don't see drive `Media1` mounted anywhere anymore.

Comment: Apparently, [it is a deliberate feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/380033/59928). The answer there refers to [this discussion](https://lists.archive.carbon60.com/linux/kernel/855705#855705), I don't fully understand the reasoning in the quoted email, but apparently it is a case of "never ever break userspace" kernel rule. Reflinks just happen to not work across bind-mounts on the same device, and apparently that feature became used in apps like Podman/Docker for containerization purposes *(it's just my theory from the comment)*, so one can't "undo" that behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55387608

Comment: @mook765: The Media1 line wasn't rendering while on same line as the backticks; fixed it. if I'm reading your and @Hi-Angel's links correctly, Even though `/mnt/mymedia/share/pics` and `/mnt/Media2/share` live alongside each other, `ln` considers them different because the parent `/mnt/mymedia/share` lives on `/mnt/Media1`? Or could it (unlikely) be related to the directories living so close to `/mnt`?